# Should I use asynchronous MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, perl, sockets, asynchronous

Currently, I'm working on a socket server in Perl. The server accepts a client, and listens for an array of commands that sometimes may get or set values in a MySQL table (about 45 - 65% of the time, not always). The server will have quite a few clients connected and using it at once (100+).

My question (as you can tell from the title) is: Should I use asynchronous MySQL queries? I know I may get a benefit from using asynchronous MySQL on queries that I don't need to get any output from (where I set values, etc), but would a query with output really take enough time that I would need asynchronous MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

The time a query takes mainly depends on the query itself, the structure of your database and the amount of data you are looking at.

Asynchronous querying would have the benefit that your script continues without the need to  wait for the server response.

I am not very familiar with perl but in order to fetch the data returned after an async query you will need some kind of callback function which is executed once the server responses.